# Alt + tab shortcut skipping youtube fullscreen mode window

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Alt + tab shortcut not working with google chrome when the youtube tab is open in fullscreen mode. It's switching to the next recent window instead of the youtube window.

Could someone help me fix it

Answer (score 1):

This has been an issue for a few years. As I recall they once fixed it and then it broke again with a new release of Chrome. Sorry buddy, I think we'll have to live with this until it is fixed again. I personally have switched over to Firefox for now, and can confirm that it is working there.